# Avoid signing of apk with different keystores/certificates

Tags: android, react-native, release, x509certificate, apktool

Im working on a react-native android application in which I have decompiled the generated signed apk, made the changes in the code and recompiled the apk back with apktool and signed the same apk with a other certificate file which is not its original sign certifcate which I use to generate the release apk. I dont want it to get signed if my orginal certificate is not used for signing the modified apk. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not original certificate You cannot do that

Comment: Can you give a bit of insigth on this ?

Comment: "and signed the same apk with a other certificate" - You must use the original certificate here